# QAction::setShortcuts() only responds to the first shortcut in the list

Tags: macos, qt

I want a QAction to be triggered by multiple keyboard shortcuts. According to the documentation, this should be possible by passing a list of QKeySequences to [QAction::setShortcuts()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#setShortcuts) , but in practice it seems that only the first key sequence in the list is used.

I've created a short example that demonstrates the problem. Here I'm trying to have both <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (which are <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on the Mac) trigger "My Action". In this form, only <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will trigger the action. If the two shortcuts are swapped so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is first, then it will trigger the action and <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> will not. Finally, if all of the shortcut list stuff is commented out and the line with QKeySequence::Cut is uncommented, only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> will work even though [the documentation says](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html#setShortcuts) that it maps to both <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> on the Mac. The code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QAction>

MainWindow::MainWindow() {
    QMenu* menu = new QMenu("Menu");
    menuBar()->addMenu(menu);
    QAction* action = new QAction("My Action", this);
    // Create a list with two shortcuts
    QList<QKeySequence> shortcuts;
    shortcuts.append(QKeySequence(Qt::META + Qt::Key_K));
    shortcuts.append(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_X));
    action->setShortcuts(shortcuts);
    // Alternatively, use one of the QKeySequence::StandardKey enums
    //action->setShortcuts(QKeySequence::Cut);
    connect(action, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(doIt()));
    menu->addAction(action);
}

// slot
void MainWindow::doIt() { qDebug("MainWindow::doIt()"); }
```

If it matters, I'm using Mac OS X 10.9.2, and I've tried this with Qt 5.2.1 and Qt 5.3.0.

I'm including the header file and main.cpp in case anyone wants to just copy-and-paste to run the example, but there is nothing interesting or non-standard in them. Header file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

public slots:
    void doIt();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple keyboard shortcuts for a menu item are not supported on OS X. The [QAction documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qaction.html#setShortcuts) notes "The result of calling this function will depend on the currently running platform".

It looks like the underlying cause is that OS X [keeps the menu -> key shortcut mappings in a dictionary](http://lists.apple.com/archives/projectbuilder-users/2001/Feb/msg00135.html) with the menu text as the key and the value as a single key atom (not any sort of collection), so there can be only one active key shortcut per menu item at a time.

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/526072/7709) a user found that even manually adding multiple keyboard shortcuts for the same menu item in a native application did not work - only the first was used.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting this was a platform-specific thing and had noticed the note in QAction's documentation, but I wasn't sure if that was the problem here.

Comment: It is odd that the docs don't mention this. You'd think somebody else would have run into it by now.

Comment: I've submitted a Qt documentation bug for this: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-39127