# Qt on macOS: display two keyboard shortcuts for one menu item

Tags: c++, macos, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm writing an app using Qt 5 on macOS, and I'd like to find a way to display more than one keyboard shortcut for a menu item. It's not necessary for either shortcuts to actually work as I'm utilizing a different mechanism for triggering the shortcuts than the usual method with QAction. I just want both shortcuts to be displayed in the menu. Something like:

[image: mockup of menu item with multiple keystrokes]

I've tried using QAction::setKeyboardShortcuts, but only the first shortcut is displayed.

I've also tried using a facility of QAction where you specify a shortcut in its text using a tab character (e.g. `"Throw Party\tCtrl+P"`), but adding more than one shortcut (e.g. `"Throw Party\tCtrl+P Ctrl+Alt+A"`) results in none being displayed at all, unless they're separated by a comma, in which case a) they display with buggy formatting, and b) it implies that it's one shortcut that requires two consecutive keystrokes, rather than two separate shortcuts.

Comment: I think your question is answered here, but you aren't going to like it...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762662/qactionsetshortcuts-only-responds-to-the-first-shortcut-in-the-list